# Display multidimensional array elements in smarty

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display array elements in smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609929/display-array-elements-in-smarty)

I have merged two mysql results :

```
while($rs_1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1)) {
    $arr1[] = $rs_1;
}
while($rs_2 = mysql_fetch_array($r2)) {
    $arr2[] = $rs_2;
}
$resN = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
```

`var_dump($resN)` shows the following result :

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> string(6) "Petric" 
        ["bz_pro_first_name"]=> string(6) "Petric" 
        [1]=> string(8) "Naughton" 
        ["bz_pro_last_name"]=> string(8) "Naughton" 
    }
    [1]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> string(6) "Nitish" 
        ["bz_pro_first_name"]=> string(6) "Nitish" 
        [1]=> string(12) "Dolakasharia" 
        ["bz_pro_last_name"]=> string(12) "Dolakasharia"
    }
    [2]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> string(6) "Martin" 
        ["bz_pro_first_name"]=> string(6) "Martin" 
        [1]=> string(3) "Rom" 
        ["bz_pro_last_name"]=> string(3) "Rom"
    }
    [3]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(5) "Steve" 
        ["bz_pro_first_name"]=> string(5) "Steve" 
        [1]=> string(5) "Wough" 
        ["bz_pro_last_name"]=> string(5) "Wough" 
    } 
    [4]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> string(3) "Liz" 
        ["bz_pro_first_name"]=> string(3) "Liz" 
        [1]=> string(6) "Hurley" 
        ["bz_pro_last_name"]=> string(6) "Hurley"
    }
}
```

I am supposed to display them in smarty so :

```
assign_values('rand_pro',$resN);
```

Now I tried to display in smarty like this :

```
{foreach name=outer item=pro from=$rand_pro}
                    {foreach key=key item=item from=$pro}
                        {$key}: {$item}<br />
                    {/foreach}
                    {/foreach}
```

It displays the results but serially. I need to extract the values in some positions . So how can I extract the values eg first name, last name etc ?

Answer (score 0):

{$item.bz_pro_last_name}
{$key.bz_pro_first_name}

Not sure if I got your question but try the above inside your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can write foreach loop like this.

```
{foreach from=$rand_pro item=pro key=pro_key}
    {$key}: {$pro.bz_pro_first_name} {$pro.bz_pro_last_name}<br />
{/foreach}
```